# Error implementing Navigation Guard in a Vue 3 + Quasar + TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api, quasar-framework

I am working on an application using the Quasar Framework along with Vue 3 (utilizing Composition API with  syntax) and TypeScript. I am attempting to implement a Navigation Guard in my routes.ts file to handle route authentication, but I am encountering the following error:

```
ERROR in src/router/index.ts:26:5
TS2740: Type 'Router' is missing the following properties from type 'readonly RouteRecordRaw[]': length, concat, join, slice, and 16 more.
    24 |   const Router = createRouter({
    25 |     scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
  > 26 |     routes,
       |     ^^^^^^
    27 |
    28 |     // Leave this as is and make changes in quasar.conf.js instead!
    29 |     // quasar.conf.js -> build -> vueRouterMode
```

Here's what I've tried so far:

1. I initially set up the Navigation Guard following the standard Vue 3 documentation.
   Upon encountering the error, I attempted to modify the quasar.config.js file's vueRouterMode to 'history' instead of 'hash', as suggested in some forums.
2. I also verified that all dependencies are updated and checked for any typos or misconfigurations in my code.
3. Despite these efforts, the error remains unchanged. I expected that updating the vueRouterMode or verifying the code for mistakes would resolve the error, but it has persisted.

routes.ts

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory, RouteRecordRaw } from 'vue-router';
import { useAuthStore } from 'src/stores/auth-store'; // Ensure you import your auth store
import MainLayout from 'layouts/MainLayout.vue';
import AdminLayout from 'layouts/AdminLayout.vue';
import IndexPage from 'pages/IndexPage.vue';
import SignUp from 'pages/Authentication/SignUp.vue';
import SignIn from 'pages/Authentication/SignIn.vue';
import DashboardPage from 'pages/SuperAdmin/DashboardPage.vue';

const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    component: MainLayout,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: SignUp },
      { path: '/home', component: IndexPage },
      { path: '/login', component: SignIn }
    ],
  },
  {
    path: '/admin',
    component: AdminLayout,
    children: [
      { path: '', component: DashboardPage },
    ],
    meta: { requiresAdmin: true }
  },
  {
    path: '/:catchAll(.*)*',
    component: () => import('pages/ErrorNotFound.vue'),
  },
];
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,  // This is correct
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const auth = useAuthStore();

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
    if (auth.isAdminUser) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/');
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});

export default router;
```

auth-store.ts

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';
import AuthRequests from 'boot/api/AuthRequests';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import { api } from 'boot/axios';
import { Roles } from 'src/utils/Constants'


interface AuthState {
  jwt: string | null;
  expiration: number | null;
}

interface DecodedJWT {
  permissions?: string[];
  exp: number;
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore('auth', {
  state: (): AuthState => {
    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('authStore') as string) || {
      jwt: null,
      expiration: null
    };
  },
  getters: {
    isAuthenticated: (state: AuthState): boolean => {
      return state.jwt !== null;
    },
    hasPermission: (state: AuthState) => (permission: string): boolean => {
      if (!state.jwt) return false;
      const decoded_jwt: DecodedJWT = jwt_decode(state.jwt);
      return decoded_jwt.permissions ? decoded_jwt.permissions.includes(permission) : false;
    },
    isAdminUser: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.ADMIN),
    isVenueOwner: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.VENUE_OWNER),
    isStaff: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.STAFF),
    isEventOrganizer: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.EVENT_ORGANIZER),
    isGroupAdmin: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.GROUP_ADMIN),
    isStandardUser: (): boolean => useAuthStore().hasPermission(Roles.USER),
  },
  actions: {
    async authenticate(email: string, password: string): Promise<void> {
      try {
        const { data } = await AuthRequests.authenticate(email, password);
        const decoded_jwt: DecodedJWT = jwt_decode(data);

        this.jwt = data;
        this.expiration = decoded_jwt.exp;
        api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + data;

        localStorage.setItem('authStore', JSON.stringify({
          jwt: data,
          expiration: decoded_jwt.exp,
        }));
      } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
      }
    },
    logout(): void {
      this.jwt = null;
      delete api.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'];
      localStorage.removeItem('authStore');
    }
  }
});
```

src/router/index.ts

```
import { route } from 'quasar/wrappers';
import {
  createMemoryHistory,
  createRouter,
  createWebHashHistory,
  createWebHistory,
} from 'vue-router';
import routes from './routes';

export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory);

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    history: createHistory(
      process.env.MODE === 'ssr' ? void 0 : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
    ),
  });

  return Router;
});
```

Comment: what is `routes` in router/index.ts??  if it's causing an error, it would help to see what it is and where it's coming from... is it the same thing being exported from routes.ts?  If so, you've exported an entire router object and are trying to use it in the creation of another router.  `routes` should **only** be an array of routes.  If you're creating a router in both routes.ts and index.ts you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Update the question with the contents of `src/router/index.ts`. That's where the error is. Without that code, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Yes, I did not realize that it was missing. I have updated my question. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you are creating the router twice, once in index.ts and once in routes.ts. I would suggest keeping the creation inside index.ts and to just add the guard there. Basically remove this from `routes.ts` and only export `routes`:

```
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,  // This is correct
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const auth = useAuthStore();

  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
    if (auth.isAdminUser) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/');
    }
  } else {
    next();
  }
});
```

and add this to `index.ts`:

```
export default route(function (/* { store, ssrContext } */) {
  const createHistory = process.env.SERVER
    ? createMemoryHistory
    : (process.env.VUE_ROUTER_MODE === 'history' ? createWebHistory : createWebHashHistory);

  const Router = createRouter({
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ left: 0, top: 0 }),
    routes,

    history: createHistory(
      process.env.MODE === 'ssr' ? void 0 : process.env.VUE_ROUTER_BASE
    ),
  });

  Router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    const auth = useAuthStore();

    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAdmin)) {
      if (auth.isAdminUser) {
        next();
      } else {
        next('/');
      }
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });

  return Router;
});
```

Comment: The error has been resolved. Thank you so much!

Comment: You might want to accept this answer to mark this question as resolved.